# Why does my CardView first item (position 0) starts 2 activities instead of 1?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview

I am trying to start an activity based on the CardView Item, I have tried starting an activity with setOnItemClickListener by using the position of the CardView. But only when (position 0) is clicked it will launch (position 1) activity followed by (position 0) activity.

Here is myAdapter setOnItemClickListener

```
myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent activityOne = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityOne.class);
                        activityOne.putExtra("title", "Restaurant One");
                        startActivity(activityOne);
                    case 1:
                        Intent activityTwo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityTwo.class);
                        activityTwo.putExtra("title", "Restaurant Two");
                        startActivity(activityTwo);
                }
                String title = customList.get(position).getTextHeader();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

ItemListAdapter code

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Item> myList;
    private OnItemClickListener myListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        myListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView Logo;
        public TextView Header;
        public TextView Desc;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            Logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restImage);
            Header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
            Desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ItemListAdapter(ArrayList<Item> exampleList) {
        myList = exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, myListener);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item currentItem = myList.get(position);
        holder.Logo.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.Header.setText(currentItem.getTextHeader());
        holder.Desc.setText(currentItem.getTextDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the cards title to start my activites instead and it is working fine.
`String title = customList.get(position).getTextHeader();`
But I still do not know how does the positions of the CardView work.

Comment: You need to `break;` in `case 0:`, at least. In Java, `switch` will fall through to the next `case` unless you tell it to `break`.